# How to data from tabe to combobox dynamically

Tags: php, mysqli, combobox

how can i put the $CATEGORY dynamically so that whatever i click on the table it will retrieved in the combo box? (without settng its id to any number like 5 )

```
<?php
 $CATEGORY = 5; //from DB table, consider 5 as category id for sample

 $sql="SELECT tblcourse.id as id, tblcourse.course as course FROM tblcourse";
 $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

 $options="";
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $id=$row["id"];
 $thing=$row["course"];
 $isSel = ($CATEGORY == $id)?"selected":'';
 $options.= " <OPTION VALUE='$id' $isSel>$thing</option>";
 }
 ?>
```

My Combobox form code below :

```
<select name="cbocourse" style="height:35px; width:280px; background-color:#923227; box- shadow:1px 1px #FFF;color:#C90;" onClick="submitCATEGORY();">
<option value="<?php echo $CATEGORY; ?>">
<?php echo $options;?></option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your combobox code is wrong : you cannot parse a list of option into another super option, it means nothing. Just parse your $options between your select tags.
Just be sure to reload your page (or page fragment with AJAX for example) each time you call submitCATEGORY(), in order to regenerate your html combobox.
Your PHP code seems good.

Comment: how to do that? can you pls give me an example? or better if you correct my codings :(

Comment: Just write your HTML that way : 
`<select name="cbocourse" style="height:35px; width:280px; background-color:#923227; box-shadow:1px 1px #FFF;color:#C90;" onChange="submitCATEGORY();">
<?php echo $options; ?>
</select>`

Comment: Also, on a combobox it's better to bind your function call to the onChange event, rather than onClick.

Comment: Set it to the value submitted through your form to your PHP script. For example, if your form is set to POST method, you can catch your chosen category in $_POST['cbocourse'].

Comment: <?php
@$a=$_POST['cbocourse'];
 $CATEGORY =  $a; //from DB table, consider 3 as category id for sample

 $sql="SELECT tblcourse.id as id, tblcourse.course as course FROM tblcourse";
 $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

 $options="";
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id=$row["id"];
    $thing=$row["course"];
    $isSel = ($CATEGORY == $id)?"selected":'';
    $options.= " <OPTION VALUE='$id' $isSel>$thing</option>";
 }
 ?>
I TRIED THE CODE BUT IT DIDNT WORK :(

Comment: HERES MY CODE FOR COMBO BOX

<select name="cbocourse" style="height:35px; width:280px; background-color:#923227; box-shadow:1px 1px #FFF;color:#C90;" onChange="submitCATEGORY();"> <?php echo $options; ?> </select>

Comment: Be sure to set your form method='post'. Also you forgot to correct the MySQL request with the WHERE statement.

Comment: Can you please give me the code for it? I cant find any solution. I am hopeless that i can resolve this :(